# how do "dropping out of scope" and "being moved" behave differently on reborrow in Rust?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

If I understand it correctly, in Rust, a reborrow's lifetime must be shorter than what it reborrows from:

```rust
let mut x = ...;
let m1 = &mut x;
let m2 = &mut *m;
let m3 = m1; // m1 moved here
let m4 = m2; // use m2 here
```

moving `m1` to `m3` will trigger an error, because `m1` is bororwed by `m2`, which is used later.

However, dropping out of scope behaves differently in this case, as the following compiles:

```rust
let mut x = ...;
let m2 : &mut ...;
{
    let m1 = &mut x;
    m2 = &mut *m1;
} // m1 drop out of scope here
let m4 = m2; // use m2 here
```

If `m2` is a borrow, instead of a reborrow, to `m1`, then both cases fail to compile.

Now, I understand why the behavior of the compiler is safe. In the moving case, one end up with two mutable borrow to the same variable, which is unsound. In the dropping out of scope case, the mutable borrow dies anyway, and the reborrow still points to valid data.
But I wonder:

- how can this behavior be interpreted in terms of lifetime and typing rules?
- where can I find relevant information about the detailed behavior? Are they present in the document, or should I refer to the source code of `rustc`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be "interpreted" in terms of lifetime, and it's actually much more than that. Lifetimes are not simply a handy way to describe otherwise too complex operations done by the compiler: they **are** the abstraction used by the compiler to deal with ownership and borrows. That is, the compiler will compute the lifetime of *every* variable, so it knows when it has to free memory for these variables.

Let's walk step by step how it would do that on your examples. Note that `'lifetime: { ... }` is not valid syntax, but we'll use to mean *denote by `'lifetime` the lifetime of this scope*. In the same vein, `let a: 'a = ...` is not valid syntax, but we'll use it to mean a's lifetime is `'a`.

The goal is the following: if I have a lifetime that is bound to a scope, this is a *known* lifetime, because I know for how long it ensures values of that lifetime will live. Therefore, I should be able to create scopes so that variables' lifetime are exactly the scopes' ones, and that respect the relationship between variable's lifetimes.

#### The first example

We start by naming each lifetime.

```rust
struct Foo; // Does not implement `Copy`

'outer: {           // Code has to live in a scope (it might be `main`, for example)
  let mut x: 'x = Foo;
  let m1: 'm1 = &mut x;
  let m2: 'm2 = &mut *m1;
  let m3: 'm3 = m1; // m1 moved here
  let m4: 'm4 = m2; // use m2 here
}
```

The first relationship that we may see are:

- `'x: 'm1`;
- `'x: 'm2`;
- `'x: 'm3`;
- `'x: 'm4`.

These are to be read *`'x` outlives `'mX`*, meaning in the end, the scope for which `'x` is valid must enclose `'mX`'s scope.

Other relationships are:

- `'m3` must start where `'m1` ends, due to the definition of `m3`;
- similarly, `'m4` must start where `'m2` ends, due to the definition of `m2`.

These are due to the fact that `&mut T` is non-`Copy`, so `m1` and `m3` must be moved.

The other constraints are due to exclusive borrow rules of Rust, and are `'mX` must be disjoint from `'mY` for `X` ≠ `Y`.

Also, implicitly, `'outer` outlives everything. In this example, you may think of `'outer` as `'static`, because the only requirement is that `'static` must outlive everything.

Now that we have enumerated the constraints, we can try solving the problem, that is, "solve for the unknowns `'x`, `'m1`, `'m2`, `'m3` and `'m4`". The first step is by assigning a lifetime to `'x`, since it's easy. It has no constraints of being outlived by anyone besides `'outer`, which is a scope's lifetime, so let's assign `'x` = `'outer`. Due to our implicit assumption, this complies with the first four constraints, and actually makes them void (they are true by definition of `'outer`, so nothing to worry anymore about).

Then, we want to try and find scopes that will satisfy the moving condition.

```rust
'outer: {
  let mut x: 'x = Foo;
  let m1: 'm1 = &mut x;               // ---------\
                                      //          |- `'m1`
  let m2: 'm2 = &mut *m1;             // ---------+--\
                                      //          |  |
  let m3: 'm3 = m1;                   // ---------/  |- `'m2`
                                      //             |
  let m4: 'm4 = m2;                   // ------------/
}
```

We don't have much freedom here, as we are told exactly when `'m1` and `'m2` start and end. Now comes the contradiction: `'m1` and `'m2` must be disjoint, what they clearly are not! That is, you won't be able to find a scope, like we did for `'x`, that will satisfy all the conditions.

#### The second example

Let's name things like we did in the first example.

```
'outer: {
  let mut x: 'x = Foo;
  let m2: 'm2;
  'inner: {
    let m1: 'm1 = &mut x;
    m2 = &mut *m1;
  }
  let m4: 'm4 = m2;
}
```

For this second example, I think we can go a little bit faster and skip some steps. As in the first example, you may go for `'x` = `'outer` right away. Now, you may be tempted to do `'m1` = `'inner`, but it's not the case because `'m1` must end when `m2` is assigned.
Instead, the following lifetimes should be chosen

```rust
'outer: {
  let mut x = Foo;
  let m2: 'm2;
  'inner: {
    let m1: 'm1 = &mut x;       // ------\ 
                                //       |- `'m1`
    m2 = &mut *m1;              // ------+
  }                             //       |- `'m2`
                                //       |
  let m4: 'm4 = m2;             // ------+
                                //       |- `'m4`
                                // ------/
}
```

In this case, you notice no one used the `'inner` scope as their lifetime's scope, so you can actually get rid of it.

```rust
'outer: {
  let mut x = Foo;
  let m2: 'm2;
  let m1: 'm1 = &mut x;       // ------\ 
                              //       |- `'m1`
  m2 = &mut *m1;              // ------+
                              //       |- `'m2`
  let m4: 'm4 = m2;           // ------+
                              //       |- `'m4`
                              // ------/
}
```

Now that it's written this way, you can also declare `'m2` at the same time as you define it.

```rust
'outer: {
  let mut x = Foo;
  let m1: 'm1 = &mut x;       // ------\ 
                              //       |- `'m1`
  let m2: 'm2 = &mut *m1;     // ------+
                              //       |- `'m2`
  let m4: 'm4 = m2;           // ------+
                              //       |- `'m4`
                              // ------/
}
```

Let's strip out all the lifetime markers.

```rust
let mut x = Foo;
let m1 = &mut x;
let m2 = m1;
let m4 = m2;
```

*Et voilà*! This is actually closer to what Rust will *do* (in the sense, what the compiled code is going to do) — assuming these variable swaps won't get optimised away. Also, the compiler now knows the lifetime of every variable.

#### A brief ending note

Keep in mind that this is not exactly what the compiler actually does. The algorithm is more complex, there are corner cases and I've overlook a few details. However, the main point is that you can keep this as your mental model for what the compiler does. It is accurate enough to understand compilation errors, to understand how to write correct code or patch code that was not correct in the first place, and it's simple enough for you to "run" it without actually having to take a paper and a pen (at least when you get used to it).

Comment: I think your explanation can indeed cleanly explain the two examples I give. But I still somehow wonder how reborrow should be interpreted in your model. If I swap the last two lines in my first example, the code will compile (not so if `m2` borrows directly from `x`).

Comment: Being perfectly fair, I did not go into details about that, because that would have made my post even longer, but you can still apply the same reasoning. The more detailly version would be that in the second example, `m1` is invalidated when moved to `m2`, and `m2` is invalidated when moved to `m4`. On the other hand, if you switched the two last lines of the first example, you would not invalidate `m1` at the moment of the reborow: you only enforce that there are no other usages of it until the last reborrow is droped. Pretty much like for `x`. It compiles because ` the last borrow is `m4`,

Comment: which is droped before `m1` is used again, when moved to `m3`.

Comment: @julthu: i can't understand why this portion of your code compiles:
        'outer: {           // Code has to live in a scope (it might be `main`, for example)
            let mut x = Foo;
            let m1 = &mut x;
            let m2 = &mut *m1;
            let m3 = m1; // m1 moved here
            //let m4 = m2; // use m2 here
        }

Which is the difference between "let m1 = &mut x;"  and  "let m2 = &mut *m1;"

In my mind they are mutable references the same DATA so I expect that the code does not compiles

Comment: @openyourmind `let m2 = &mut *m1` is a reborrow. Reborrowing is a pretty advanced topic, I can't really explain it in a single SO comment. As for the example, it does *not* compile (see the original question).