# I can't understand ownership in Rust

Tags: rust, ownership

I'm an absolute beginner with Rust (with a poor english) and I'm having some trouble with the concept of ownership, and reading the following passage from the book "Programming Rust - Fast, Safe System Development" gives me the impression that it's important, but I can't quite understand it.
Below is the passage I need help with.

> [image]
>
> Each kind of reference affects what we can do with the values along
> the owning path to the referent, and the values reachable from the
> referent (Figure 5-9). Note that in both cases, the path of ownership
> leading to the referent cannot be changed for the reference’s
> lifetime. For a shared borrow, the path is read-only; for a mutable
> borrow, it’s completely inaccessible. So there’s no way for the
> program to do anything that will invalidate the reference.

The examples provided by the book are not of great help to me, and I propose to use the following data structure in the examples (but any other better idea, even if different, is more than welcome)

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct InnerData {
    if1: i32,
    if2: String,
    if3: (char, i32),
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct OuterData {
    of1: String,
    of2: char,
    of3: Box<InnerData>,
}
```

Can you help me with some meaningful examples that map to the concepts in the book excerpt?

Comment: As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)

Answer (score 3):

I'm reading the book, too. I think the terms "ownership" and "borrow" can be confusing, so I won't use them.  Also, I think you need another level of nesting to mimic the diagrams, so I'm going to use the following nested structs for my examples:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct A {
    one: i32,
    two: B,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct B {
    three: String,
    four: C,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct C {
    five: String,
    six: i32,
}
```

**Left picture example**:

```
fn main() {

    let mut a = A {
        one: 10,
        two: B {
            three: "hello".to_string(),
            four: C { 
                five: "world".to_string(),
                six: 20, 
            }
        },
    };

    println!("{:?}", a.two.four);

    a.two.four.six = 20;
    println!("{}", a.two.four.six);

}
```

output:

```
C { five: "world", six: 20 }
20
```

Conclusion: The variable `a` can read the C struct and change it--as well as any other values in the tree.

**Middle picture**:

```
fn main() {

    let mut a = A {
        one: 10,
        two: B {
            three: "hello".to_string(),
            four: C { 
                five: "world".to_string(),
                six: 20, 
            }
        },
    };

    let c_ref = &a.two.four;
    println!("{}", c_ref.five);

    println!("{:?}", a.two);
}
```

output:

```
world
B { three: "hello", four: C { five: "world", six: 20 } }
```

Conclusions:

1. The reference `c_ref` can read values below it in the tree.
2. The variable `a` can read any values in the tree.

Questions:

Can `c_ref` change any values?

```
let c_ref = &a.two.four;
println!("{}", c_ref.five);

c_ref.six = 30; //<=== ERROR
```

Can `a` change `two`, i.e. something in the tree above the value that `c_ref` refers to?

```
fn main() {

    let mut a = A {
        one: 10,
        two: B {
            three: "hello".to_string(),
            four: C { 
                five: "world".to_string(),
                six: 20, 
            }
        },
    };


    let c_ref = &a.two.four;
    println!("{}", c_ref.five);

    println!("{:?}", a.two);

    a.two = B {
        three: "goodbye".to_string(),
        four: C {
            five: "mars".to_string(),
            six: 101,
        }
    };

    println!("{}", c_ref.six); //<== ERROR

}
```

I expected the error to be on the previous line--the assignment statement--but when I omit the last line, there is no error.  I guess the assignment to `a.three` invalidates `c_ref`, so it's not until you try to use `c_ref` again that it causes an error.

Can `a` change something not directly above `c_ref` in the tree?

```
fn main() {

    let mut a = A {
        one: 10,
        two: B {
            three: "hello".to_string(),
            four: C { 
                five: "world".to_string(),
                six: 20, 
            }
        },
    };

    let c_ref = &a.two.four;
    println!("{}", c_ref.five);

    a.one = 105;
    println!("{}", a.one);

}
```

output:

```
world
105
```

No issues there.

**Right picture**:

```
fn main() {

    let mut a = A {
        one: 10,
        two: B {
            three: "hello".to_string(),
            four: C { 
                five: "world".to_string(),
                six: 20, 
            }
        },
    };


    let c_ref = &mut a.two.four;
    c_ref.five = "mars".to_string();

    println!("{}", c_ref.five);

}
```

output:

```
mars
```

The `mutable c_ref` can change something below it in the tree.

Question:

Can `a` access anything below `mutable c_ref`?

```
fn main() {

    let mut a = A {
        one: 10,
        two: B {
            three: "hello".to_string(),
            four: C { 
                five: "world".to_string(),
                six: 20, 
            }
        },
    };

    let c_ref = &mut a.two.four;
    c_ref.five = "mars".to_string();

    println!("{}", c_ref.five);
    println!("{}", a.two.four.five);

}
```

output:

```
mars
mars
```

The book seems to say that `a` should not be able to access anything below `mutable c_ref`.  And, the book seems to say that `a` cannot access anything above `mutable c_ref` either, but the following also works:

```
fn main() {

    let mut a = A {
        one: 10,
        two: B {
            three: "hello".to_string(),
            four: C { 
                five: "world".to_string(),
                six: 20, 
            }
        },
    };

    let c_ref = &mut a.two.four;
    c_ref.five = "mars".to_string();

    println!("{}", c_ref.five);
    println!("{}", a.two.four.five);

    println!("{:?}", a.two);  //<=== Added this line

}
```

output:

```
mars
mars
B { three: "hello", four: C { five: "mars", six: 20 } }
```

Surprisingly, I can even use `a` to change something below `mutable c_ref` in the tree:

```
fn main() {

    let mut a = A {
        one: 10,
        two: B {
            three: "hello".to_string(),
            four: C { 
                five: "world".to_string(),
                six: 20, 
            }
        },
    };

    let c_ref = &mut a.two.four;
    c_ref.five = "mars".to_string();

    println!("{}", c_ref.five);
    println!("{}", a.two.four.five);

    println!("{:?}", a.two); 

    // *** ADDED THESE LINES ****
    a.two.four.five = "jump".to_string();
    println!("{}", a.two.four.five); 

}
```

output:

```
mars
mars
B { three: "hello", four: C { five: "mars", six: 20 } }
jump
```

Based on those results, "Programming Rust (Revised 2nd Edition)" seems to be wrong when it says there can be only a single writer in existence at any point in your code.  On p. 103-104, the book says:

> If you have a mutable reference to a value, you may both read and
> modify the value.  However, you may not have any other references of
> any sort to that value active at the same time...In fact, this rule
> doesn't apply only to references; it covers the borrowed value's owner
> as well...if there is a mutable reference to a value, it has exclusive
> access to the value; you can't even use the owner at all, until the
> mutable reference goes away.

Yet, I was able to use `a` to both read and write values while `mutable c_ref` was active.

**EDIT**:
Apparently, scope works like this in Rust(see comments):

```
fn main() {

    let mut a = A {
        one: 10,
        two: B {
            three: "hello".to_string(),
            four: C { 
                five: "world".to_string(),
                six: 20, 
            }
        },
    };

    let c_ref = &mut a.two.four;
    c_ref.five = "mars".to_string();
        
    println!("{}", c_ref.five);
    //After this point, the compiler notices that c_ref is never used again
    //so the scope of `c_ref` ends here.  That means that past this point 
    //there are no "active" mutable references to the variable `a`.
    
    //Therefore `a` can read any fields in the struct:
    println!("{}", a.two.four.five); 
    println!("{:?}", a.two);
    
    //And `a` can change any fields in the struct:
    a.two.four.five = "jump".to_string();
    println!("{}", a.two.four.five); 

}
```

output:

```
mars
mars
B { three: "hello", four: C { five: "mars", six: 20 } }
jump
```

Look at the difference here (notice the new function at the top):

```
fn go(c_ref: &mut C) {
    c_ref.six = 200;
}

fn main() {

    let mut a = A {
        one: 10,
        two: B {
            three: "hello".to_string(),
            four: C { 
                five: "world".to_string(),
                six: 20, 
            }
        },
    };

    let c_ref = &mut a.two.four;
    c_ref.five = "mars".to_string();
    //Notice that c_ref is used again on the last line of main() below;
    //therefore c_ref is still in scope until main() ends.

    //Because the mutable c_ref is still "active", the variable `a`
    //cannot change the values anywhere along the path to `c_ref` (either above or below `c_ref`):
    a.two.four.five = "jump".to_string();  //<====ERROR

    //Nor can `a` read any values along the path to `c_ref`:
    //println!("{}", a.two.four.five);  //Uncomment this line, and comment out the line above. Still ERROR.

    go(c_ref);
}
```

The [section on References](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html) in "The Rust Programming Language" hints at how scope is different in Rust and how blocks delimited by braces do not necessarily determine the extent of a variable's scope; instead Rust will shorten a variable's scope if the variable is no longer used in a block.

Comment: It is interesting that you find an example that seems to contradict the book, however as is it is hard to understand why exactly, because Rust will happily shorten the lifespan of a mutable borrow if possible, if that allows accessing something that shouldn't be accessible while the mutable borrow is valid. Could you provide the whole code that contradicts the book in one snippet?

Comment: @jthulhu, I edited my answer to include the full code example. In the picture on the left, everything is on the heap, so I tried changing the assignment to `let a = Box::new(A{.....` where all fields were either Box or String, but it made no difference in my results.

Comment: Ownership is, indeed, not about whether the data lies on the head or on the stack. In fact, you could remove all the `Box`es in the examples, they are not relevant here. As for your counterexample, as I suspected, `c_ref`'s scope is reduced by Rust so that it doesn't prevent reads and writes on `a_ref`. To prevent that, you can try to interleave a read/write on `c_ref` and a read/write on something "above" C. For instance, you could move the `println!("{}", c_ref.seven)` down a line, after printing `a_ref.three.six.seven`. It should fail, for the reasons explained in the book.

Comment: @jthulhu, One issue with tracking things is: someone posted that `println!()` *implicitly* borrows a shared reference (i.e not a mutable ref).   I'm not sure how that occurs, but you would think that as soon as `println!()` returned, the implicit reference would go out of scope, and therefore the borrowed reference wouldn't affect subsequent lines of code.  However, that does not seem to be the case.  Maybe macros, like `println!()` don't return, and they leave artifacts in your code?

Comment: I would suggest reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71908291/how-do-dropping-out-of-scope-and-being-moved-behave-differently-on-reborrow/71908584#71908584), which goes a little bit more in depth about how Rust works out lifetimes.

Comment: @jthulhu, *I suspected, c_ref's scope is reduced by Rust so that it doesn't prevent reads and writes on a_ref*--I considered that.  Does the compiler look ahead in the code and see that `c_ref` isn't used anymore, and therefore the compiler considers `c_ref` to go out of scope before the end of its block?  That seems crazy to me.  Implicit borrows and implicit scopes really seem to muddy the waters for understanding what's going on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253546/discussion-between-jthulhu-and-7stud).

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie in rust too, here is some of my simple examples to demonstrate the *ownership* in rust.

```rust
pub struct Data {
    pub a: usize,
    pub b: Vec<usize>,
    pub c: String,
}

pub fn main() {
    let x = Data {
        a: 1,
        b: vec![1, 2, 3],
        c: "hello".to_string(),
    };
    // then the above instance is bound to the variable x
    // we say that x owns the instance of Data

    let y = x;
    // x is moved to y
    // if you try to use x here, it will not compile

    let mut z = y;
    // now move y to z, but z is mutable (x and y are both not mutable)

    let a_borrow = &z.a;
    // here we borrow z's a field, and z still owns the instance of Data

    println!("a in z is {}", a_borrow);
    // a_borrow is not mutable, so you cannot change z's a field through it

    let b_borrow = &mut z.b;
    // now we borrow z's b field as mutable, and z still owns the instance of Data

    // change z.b through b_borrow
    b_borrow.push(114514);

    // see if z.b is changed
    for i in z.b.iter() {
        println!("ele : {}", i);
    }
}
```

The output is

```
a in z is 1
ele : 1
ele : 2
ele : 3
ele : 114514
```